# How to get associated timestamp with time_bucket_gapfill and MIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a hypertable, sensor_data:

```
 client_id | name | profile_id |            time            | exc | sensor_id | unit | val  | valid 
-----------+------+------------+----------------------------+-----+-----------+------+------+-------
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:29:11.610973 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 37.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:29:37.2002   |   0 | 12345     | c    | 38.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:30:34.591719 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 39.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:31:04.339514 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 37.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:31:22.18442  |   0 | 12345     | c    | 38.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:31:39.362446 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 39.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:32:13.574646 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 37.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:32:41.298819 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 38.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:32:59.524967 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 39.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:33:15.794619 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 37.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:34:21.144824 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 38.5 | t
 tony      | temp | 12345      | 2023-02-14 15:34:46.447752 |   0 | 12345     | c    | 39.5 | t
```

I need to get the minimum value from the buckets with time_bucket_gapfill, but I want to see the associated time for the minimum value. For example:

```
      minbucket      | minval  |           time
---------------------+---------+----------------------------
 2023-02-14 15:29:00 |   37.5  | 2023-02-14 15:29:11.610973
 2023-02-14 15:29:30 |   38.5  | 2023-02-14 15:29:37.2002
 2023-02-14 15:30:00 |         |
 2023-02-14 15:30:30 |   39.5  | 2023-02-14 15:30:34.591719
 2023-02-14 15:31:00 |   37.5  | 2023-02-14 15:31:04.339514
 2023-02-14 15:31:30 |   39.5  | 2023-02-14 15:31:39.362446
 2023-02-14 15:32:00 |   37.5  | 2023-02-14 15:32:13.574646
 2023-02-14 15:32:30 |   38.5  | 2023-02-14 15:32:41.298819
 2023-02-14 15:33:00 |   37.5  | 2023-02-14 15:33:15.794619
 2023-02-14 15:33:30 |         |
 2023-02-14 15:34:00 |   38.5  | 2023-02-14 15:34:21.144824
 2023-02-14 15:34:30 |   39.5  | 2023-02-14 15:34:46.447752
```

I tried adding time to the group by, but that simply returned a Cartesian mess.

Here is the gapfill that produced the above data.  I added the associated timestamps by hand.

```
select time_bucket_gapfill(make_interval(secs=>30), time, start=>'2023-02-14 15:29:11.610973', finish=>'2023-02-14 15:34:46.447752') as minbucket, min(val) as minval from sensor_data group by minbucket;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but it seems to work:

```
select gf.minbucket, gf.minval, av.mintime 
from 
(select time_bucket_gapfill(make_interval(secs=>30), time, start=>'2023-02-14 15:29:11.610973', finish=>'2023-02-14 15:34:46.447752') as minbucket, min(val) as minval from reading_parameter group by minbucket) gf 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select time_bucket_gapfill(make_interval(secs=>30), time, start=>'2023-02-14 15:29:11.610973', finish=>'2023-02-14 15:34:46.447752') as minbucket, time as mintime, val as bval from reading_parameter) as av 
on av.minbucket=gf.minbucket AND av.bval=gf.minval 
order by gf.minbucket;
```